# Can I use yogurt to prevent the growth of black mold?

Tags: bacteriology

I have a mold problem in my bathroom.  There is a narrow groove between the top of my tub and the wall it is attached to where a black gunk repeatedly grows.  I can shoot the material out with a spray bottle but it grows back.

I've been taught many times that a bacterial film can prevent the growth of other bacteria, because the film created by one prevents another from colonizing that spot.  I have the inclination to think yogurt has bacteria.  If I were to clear the groove of the material, then spray the groove with a mixture of yogurt and water, would the bacteria in the yogurt colonize the freshly cleared groove and prevent the growth of what I assume to be mold?

---

I assume this is on topic as I am looking for a sort of corroboration/rejection of this scenario rooted in the biological workings of bacteria.

Comment: You need to replace the caulk, use a caulk with a mildew inhibitor.  The applications for what you are talking about would be more for treating vegetables and such like in a garden. Putting yogurt in your bathroom is strange and kinda gross.

Comment: @rhill45 - people put yogurt in their *mouths* and in their *bodies*? Why would you think a dab of yogurt around the tub is gross?

Comment: Because it smells worse than vomit

Comment: If it were possible, how would you get around the problem of water often washing away the yogurt?

Comment: @rhill45 - Speak for yourself! I would prefer yogurt to vomit any time.

Comment: Maybe we should put yogurt in tile, caulk and other hardware products. Sorry I get weary when people think yogurt, vinegar and incense will clean everything in their house. Just a personal pref!

Comment: @anongoodnurse I assume if the bacteria in the yogurt could colonize the groove, then it won't matter if the yogurt is eventually washed off, since the little ones will just cling to the surface.

Comment: Nice thought, but the bacteria need an appropriate growth medium, which would not exist in that crack area. But, as I said, nice thought. :)

Comment: ohhh, so the moist environment wouldn't be enough huh?  Post thy answer, @anongoodnurse

Comment: @rhill45 - not to extend discussions in comments, but I would be a happier camper if people cleaned their houses with a lot of water, a little vinegar or baking soda, and elbow grease, leaving all these other silly cleaning products (aerosolized and other noxious, polluting forms) in the warehouses of the money-grubbing, panic creating manufacturers where they belong.

Comment: @anongoodnurse good point re safety but if it's a toxic black mold, maybe time to pull out the big guns :/)

Comment: You should consider treating the cause instead of the symptoms. Opening the windows can do a huge part in inhibiting mold growth by reducing the humidity. Also, IMO this fits better on Life Hacks or DIY SE.